# Parse all HTML code

Tags: android

I need to copy all HTML code on the page.

I do so:

```
URL url = new URL(testurl);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
Scanner in = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
  while(in.hasNextLine()) 
   {
     htmlText=htmlText+in.nextLine(); 
    }
   in.close();
```

But if the page is large, it takes a lot of time.

Is there a faster method?

Comment: Did you tried with [Jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/) ?

Comment: how to keep HTML code?Jsoup parse just text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a different method of reading the page? Like a buffered reader? [Reading the content of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188901/reading-the-content-of-web-page) or
[Reading entire html file to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035316/reading-entire-html-file-to-string)

I'm just thinking Scanner may be a little slow.

Tim

Comment: Thanks, first link is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use (http://jsoup.org "JSoup") to download and parse the `HTML` from `URL`

You can get the `HTML` as `document` and read the text on each `elements`

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>(){
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://youturl.com").get();
            final String content;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // get the required text 
                   content = doc.body().getElementsByTag("bodyTag").text();

                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
}.execute();
```